Application navigations working very slow with playwright

   self._browser = BrowserType.create_browser(browser_type)
   self._context = self._browser.new_context(
    http_credentials = {'username': username,'password': password} if 
  username and password else None,
            )
    self._page = self._context.new_page()

This is how I am launching playwright browser and performing authentication for my application. So when it log in into the application and performs page navigation, the pages are loading extremely slow during navigation, however, my application is fast when I perform any operation on manually launched browser. Also, if I change the authentication here from HTTPS to cookie based, then also its working fine.
How can I resolve the issue here, or any alternative solution which i can use to login here
Tried cookies clearing during page creation in playwright, but dint work.

Please share a [mcve]. What's the site? Some sites throttle back clients they suspect are bots.

Updated the image of SSO login window ,which i am trying authenticate by providing http_credentials

Thanks, but there's still nothing for me to run here. Just a couple lines of innocuous/normal-looking code that shouldn't cause any problems in and of itself. The problem is likely with the site you're automating and its interaction with your script, rather than Playwright itself. So that's sort of important info for the reproduction. If the cookie-based auth works fine, why not use that?

cookie based authentication will require manual login once everytime,which is not feasible with automation.

I am getting this error in tracer -BSSO Telemetry: {"result":"Error","error":"bssoNotSupported","type":"TBAuthTelemetry","data":{"BSSO.info":"not-supported"},"traces":["BrowserSSO Initialized","window.navigator.msLaunchUri is not available for _pullBrowserSsoCookie"]}   Is that the issue why its performing too slow when page navigations also how can i resolve it.

It's kinda hard to say without something to run.
